# Trying to learn javascript integration in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, image

I am trying to learn javascript so that I can improve my Django application.

I'm trying to vary images with a javascript function based on whether the URL link exists or not, but it's not working:

Here's my javascript function:

```
    // Creates an object which can read files from the server
    var reader = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var checkFor = "https://res.cloudinary.com/.../{{ object.id }}.png";

    // Opens the file and specifies the method (get)
    // Asynchronous is true
    reader.open('get', checkFor, true);

    //check each time the ready state changes
    //to see if the object is ready
    reader.onreadystatechange = checkReadyState;

    function checkReadyState() {

        if (reader.readyState === 4) {

            //check to see whether request for the file failed or succeeded
            if ((reader.status == 200) || (reader.status == 0)) {

            //page exists -- redirect to the checked
            //checked for page
            document.location.href = checkFor;

            }
            else {

            var checkFor = "https://res.cloudinary.com/.../{{ object.system }}.png"
            return checkFor

            }

        }//end of if (reader.readyState === 4)

    }// end of checkReadyState()

    // Sends the request for the file data to the server
    // Use null for "get" mode
    reader.send(null);
```

Then I try to call 'checkFor in my HTML template:

```
<img src="checkFor"class="mx-auto" width="250px" onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src="https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image.svg"'/>
```

I just get the default image, when I know that one of the earlier URL exists. It means there is an error either in the function or when I call the variable 'checkFor'.

Comment: Are you getting any errors, in the browser console?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, it just displays this URL image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/.../image.svg"

Comment: You have `var checkFor = ...` in your `checkReadyState` function. JS behaves strangely when you use `var` it will extract all variables defined this way and create local undefined "placeholder" variables at the start of the function call. Change this to `let` and/or call the variable in the function something else